# How can i get plural price data and put them order and put in labels with c# using Selenium?

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium

I'm trying to do a price comparing website. With this code, I can get the first product price. But I need to take 6 product prices and put their labels and with the "buy" button I wanna send users to buy link. Also, I wanna to order options like low to high or high to low. How can I do that?

```
protected void Button0_Click0(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    string str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, str6;
    driver.Url = "https://www.akakce.com/arama/?q=" + TextBox2.Text;
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    str1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='pb_v8']//span[@class='pt_v8']")).GetAttribute("textContent");
    Label1.Text = ("Price: " + str1);
}
```

I've did some changes but str 1 is giving correct data first one but str 2 gives 4. product price and skipping 2 and 3. products prices. Here my edited code:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
string str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, str6;
driver.Url = "https://www.akakce.com/arama/?q=" + TextBox2.Text;
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
str1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[1]//a//span[@class='pb_v8']//span[@class='pt_v8']")).GetAttribute("textContent");
str2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[2]//a//span[@class='pb_v8']//span[@class='pt_v8']")).GetAttribute("textContent");
Label1.Text = ("Price: " + str1);
Label2.Text = ("Price: " + str2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to click on `lowest/highest` price link and then use `FindElements()` to get list of elements and then iterate

```
//click on lowest to highest
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//p[@class='lms_v8']//a[2]")).Click();
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
IList<IWebElement> elements = 
driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//h3/following::span[1]//span[@class='pt_v8']"));
foreach (IWebElement element in elements)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(element.GetAttribute("textContent"));
    }
```

---

Add value in a string list and then assign it to index..0-5

```
//click on lowest to highest
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//p[@class='lms_v8']//a[2]")).Click();
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
            IList<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//h3/following::span[1]//span[@class='pt_v8']"));
            List<string> prices = new List<string>();
            foreach (IWebElement element in elements)
            {
                prices.Add(element.GetAttribute("textContent"));
            }
            Console.WriteLine(prices[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(prices[1]);
            Console.WriteLine(prices[2]);
            Console.WriteLine(prices[3]);
            Console.WriteLine(prices[4]); 
            Console.WriteLine(prices[5]);
```

Comment: I have 6 labels their name like Label1, Label2... How can i print prices to labels?

Comment: am i need to do in 1 label for all? like in 1 label get prices by order? im applying this a website so how can i change console to website?

Comment: Label1.Text=prices[0] ; Label2.Text=prices[1]….like that

Comment: I think your original post to know get list of prices. Isn’t it.

Comment: I couldn't handle to buy button how can i do that?

Comment: @MehmetTaşkın : I don't know how you are using buy button, then how i can help you without knowing that?

Comment: i placed buttons right side to prices and when i click it i wanna redirect that specific product buy page from my source page, i cant figure it out.